# bold entries in r data.frame RMarkdown

Tags: r, dataframe, kable

I am listing my results in RMarkdown. I want to show max values in each column in bold. How can I do that?
See the code, and output (as png) below please.

```
data<-data.frame(A=c(1,2,4,3),  B=c(8,7,9,10), C=c(14,12,13,11), D=c(15,18,17,16))
rownames(data)<-c("E", "F", "G", "H")

library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

kable(data) %>%
  kable_styling(
    full_width = FALSE,
    bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"), 
  ) %>%
  add_header_above(c( '', Group1 = 2, Group2 = 2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could do this with `cell_spec`

1. Loop [`across`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) the columns of the dataset, add the `cell_spec` layer with `bold` argument as a logical vector i.e. TRUE where the column value is `max` with `==`
2. Convert to `kable` and use the OP's code as in the post

```
library(dplyr)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
data %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ cell_spec(., bold = . == max(.)))) %>%
  kable(escape = FALSE, booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  
  kable_styling(
    full_width = FALSE,
    bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"), 
  ) %>%
  add_header_above(c( '', Group1 = 2, Group2 = 2))
```

-output

[image]

---

If this needs to be by row maxs, then an option would be to `t`ranspose

```
data %>% t %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ cell_spec(., bold = . == max(.)))) %>%
  t %>%
  as.data.frame %>%
  kable(escape = FALSE, booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  
  kable_styling(
    full_width = FALSE,
    bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"), 
  ) %>%
  add_header_above(c( '', Group1 = 2, Group2 = 2))
```

-output

[image]

---

Or for the rowwise, create the `cell_spec` layer with `apply`

```
data[] <- t(apply(data, 1, function(x) cell_spec(x, bold = x == max(x))))

data %>%
  kable(escape = FALSE, booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  
  kable_styling(
    full_width = FALSE,
    bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"), 
  ) %>%
  add_header_above(c( '', Group1 = 2, Group2 = 2))
```

Or may use `dapply` from `collapse` for faster execution

```
library(collapse)
dapply(data, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) cell_spec(x, bold = x == fmax(x))) %>% 
  kable(escape = FALSE, booktabs = TRUE) %>%
  
  kable_styling(
    full_width = FALSE,
    bootstrap_options = c("striped", "hover", "condensed"), 
  ) %>%
  add_header_above(c( '', Group1 = 2, Group2 = 2))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun if I want to make it via row wise, what should I do?

Comment: @MelihAras use `row_spec` instead of `cell_spec` and that should be outside the mutate.  For columns, it is `column_spec`